# Adding Specific Posts to WP_Query Results

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

There is a complex WordPress WP_Query query. The return values of this query are posts which have 3,4 and 5 as post ID.

But no matter what the query is, the result set must contain the posts for ID=7 and ID=8 even if it doesn't match the query.

So, the result set must be like this : 3,4,5,7,8

How can i do this?

Comment: `post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 )` how about something like that? Taken from here http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: No @henrywright , It's just getting posts 2,4,12,14 and 20 if result set contains them . So `'post__in' => array(7,8)` won't work for me if post 7 and post 8 doesn't match the query.

Comment: the idea was for `post__in' => array( 2, 5, 12, 14, 20 )` to be part of the query so your result set would contain those posts!

Comment: @henrywright , so i couldn't understand what you mean. WP_Query's result set is 3,4 and 5 . If i set post__in => array(7,8) this won't add 7,8 to result set. Result set will be empty, because 7 and 8 isn't inside the result set. I hope this time i got it.

Comment: You don't apply `post__in => array( 7, 8 )` to the result set - instead you apply it to your original `WP_Query`

Comment: If you provide your query code i'll show you an example

Comment: @henrywright http://paste.ubuntu.com/7497141/

Comment: I see now after looking at your code. In that case what you could do is make 2 queries each returning an array of post IDs. Then just do `$post_ids = array_merge( $array1, $array2 );`